# Expand existing data partition of raid volume to max volume size w/o data loss

Tags: raid, disk-volume, expansion

I'm using an Areca ARC-1220 raid controller with 8x4TB HDDs (RAID-6). Initially, I had 2 volumes (à 12 TB, all data). My plan was to merge both volumes into one single volume. I deleted volume 2 (backup done) and expanded volume 1 to 24 TB (8x4-8 since RAID-6). This went fine! The partition of volume 1 was still there, and no data was lost.

Volume information looks like this on ARC-1220 web interface:

```
Volume Set Name     vs#0
Raid Set Name       rs#0
Volume Capacity     24000.0GB
SCSI Ch/Id/Lun      0/0/0
Raid Level          Raid 6
Stripe Size         128KBytes
Block Size          512Bytes
Member Disks        8
Cache Mode          Write Back
Tagged Queuing      Enabled
Volume State        Normal
```

When I run parted, I see this:

```
(parted) print free
Model: Unknown (unknown)
Disk /dev/sda1: 12.0TB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: loop

Number  Start  End     Size    File system  Flags
 1      0.00B  12.0TB  12.0TB  ext4
```

1. Partition table is `loop`. What does this mean? I expected `gpt`.
2. Why does `parted` not show free space (12 TB)?
3. Is this correct? `Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B`

When I try to resize, I see:

```
(parted) resizepart 1
End?  [12.0TB]? ^C
```

This confirms that I apparently cannot expand the volume to its max. of 24 TB.

I would like to expand the 12 TB partition to fit the 24 TB volume. All this without loss of existing data.

What do I miss?

I have backups of all data!

---

This happens when I apply parted to /dev/sda (i.s.o. /dev/sda1):

```
root@gan:~# parted /dev/sda
GNU Parted 2.3
Using /dev/sda
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) print
Error: end of file while reading Success
Retry/Ignore/Cancel? ^C
(parted)
```

---

As requested:

```
root@gan:~# lsblk -t
NAME   ALIGNMENT MIN-IO OPT-IO PHY-SEC LOG-SEC ROTA SCHED    RQ-SIZE
sda            0    512      0     512     512    1 deadline     128
└─sda1         0    512      0     512     512    1 deadline     128
sdb            0    512      0     512     512    1 deadline     128
├─sdb1         0    512      0     512     512    1 deadline     128
└─sdb2         0    512      0     512     512    1 deadline     128
sdc            0   4096      0    4096     512    1 deadline     128
└─sdc1         0   4096      0    4096     512    1 deadline     128
sr0            0    512      0     512     512    1 deadline     128
```

Is `Fix` possibly the solution?

```
root@gan:~# parted /dev/sda
GNU Parted 2.3
Using /dev/sda
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) print
Error: end of file while reading Success
Retry/Ignore/Cancel? i
Error: The backup GPT table is corrupt, but the primary appears OK, so that will be used.
OK/Cancel? o
Warning: Not all of the space available to /dev/sda appears to be used, you can fix the GPT to use all of the space (an
extra 23437501440 blocks) or continue with the current setting?
Fix/Ignore?
```

Comment: Hello, if I record correctly, gparted can do the trick. If gparted is not available, some people were able to increase an existing partion by deleting it and recreating it with fdisk : https://access.redhat.com/articles/1190213

The best option is still IMHO to create a second partition, and use LVM. It's less risky for production servers.

Comment: You are running `parted` against a partition - `sda1`. You should run it against the *whole* disk - `sda`

Comment: @shodanshok Right! My (stupid) mistake. However /dev/sdc prints error `Error: end of file while reading Success`. I complete initial posting above.

Comment: Can you show the output of `lsblk -t`?